# MVC Keeps Complaining about BODY Section

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

No matter what I do I keep getting the following error:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "body".

I keep cutting-out pieces, but I am not sure how much simpler I can make it.  Any help is appreciated.

**MY VIEW START LOOKS LIKE:**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

**MY LAYOUT LOOKS LIKE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- iOS web-app metas : hides Safari UI Components and Changes Status Bar Appearance -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- WEB FONTS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" />

    <!-- FONTS -->
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HEAD -->
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <!-- BODY -->
    <div id="main" role="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <!-- PAGE SCRIPTS -->
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**MY INDEX LOOKS LIKE:**

HELLO WORLD

Comment: don't think you need to define a `@section body` in your index.  Razor should know how where to stick the `Index.cshtml` with just `@RenderBody`

Comment: I tried it EMPTY too...yet it still fails.  Odd!

Comment: What's in your __ViewStart.cshtml_?

Comment: UPDATED the question

Comment: Can you include the code in Index.cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body is not a section. Simply remove the "@section body" and curly braces and you're good to go!

Are you sure you don't have this anywhere on your layout page?

@RenderSection("body", required: true)

Comment: Oddly...it still fails

Comment: See my edit. Sounds like you're defining a body section.

Comment: Nice handle btw ;)

Comment: No, im sorry, but I dont have @RenderSection("body", required: true) anywhere

Comment: Odd. Check your _ViewStart.cshtml to ensure you're referencing the correct layout page.

Comment: UPDATED the question

Comment: Please delete your answer so I can DELETE the question.